# Convert any array of numbers to an array of proportional values with a max value of 100

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, math

If I were to receive an array of numbers, how do I convert the numbers proportionally to the max value 100? For example, the acceptable range of numbers output must be between 0-100

*Sorry in advance for any confusion, I am struggling to phrase the question.*

Here are some examples to show what I mean:

**Input Array**: [7000, 500, 0, 850]

**Output Array**:
[70, 5, 0, 8.5]

and

**Input Array**:
[70, 550, 0, 1000]

**Output Array**:
[7, 55, 0, 100]

and

**Input Array**:
[7, 5, 0, 8.5]

**Output Array**:
[70, 50, 0, 85]

To clarify: the output will only be 100 when the max value of the input array is a power of 10.

Comment: None of those output arrays include the value `100`

Comment: Do you need the output array scaled by a power of ten? Divided by or multiplied by 1, 10, or 100?

Comment: Updated an example to include output value. Sorry about that.

Comment: Based on your output data, you should remove "and including" from the text of your question

Comment: array values are always positive ?

Comment: Yes, values are always positive.

Comment: Uh your examples all have non-positive inputs...

Comment: sorry, I meant nonnegative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something as simple as this?

```js
const scaleTo100 = (xs) => {
  const factor = 100 / 10 ** (Math .ceil (Math .log10 (Math .max (...xs))))
  return xs .map (x => x * factor)
}

console .log (scaleTo100 ([7000, 500, 0, 850]))
console .log (scaleTo100 ([70, 550, 0, 1000]))
console .log (scaleTo100 ([7, 5, 0, 8.5]))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Basically we create a `factor` that tells us what to multiply every input value to be finding the smallest power of 10 at least as large as every number, and then just multiply them.  The factor is calculated by finding the next highest power of 10 from the maximum of our input values and dividing that into 100.

Note that this will fail if all values are zero, if that's a concern.

Answer (score 0):

The term is called "normalization". I'll write in standard mathematics terminology that you can Google.

```
var input = [7000, 500, 0, 850]
var domainMin = Math.min.apply(Math, input)
var domainMax = Math.max.apply(Math, input)
var rangeMin = 0
var rangeMax = 100
var output = input.map(n => {
  var basis = (n - domainMin) / (domainMax - domainMin);
  return rangeMin + (rangeMax - rangeMin) * basis;
});

console.log(output);
// outputs [100, 7.142857142857143, 0, 12.142857142857142]
```

Now it sounds like you want to dynamically pick a different output range.

Probably, like:

```
var input = [7000, 500, 0, 850]
var domainMin = Math.min.apply(Math, input)
var domainMax = Math.max.apply(Math, input)
var rangeMin = domainMin && domainMin / Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log10(domainMin)) - 1)
var rangeMax = domainMax / Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log10(domainMax)) - 1)
console.log(rangeMin, rangeMax)
var output = input.map(n => {
  var basis = (n - domainMin) / (domainMax - domainMin);
  return rangeMin + (rangeMax - rangeMin) * basis;
});
// outputs [70, 5, 0, 8.5]
```

Comment: If I look at the output value, it does not necessarily need to be 100 as max value. Could be any value as reference that is equal or less 100

Comment: That doesn't make any sense and I disagree with the question as written

Comment: Another nice name might be stackoverflowish. Of course all questions would need to be about javascript.

Answer (score 0):

something like that ?

```js
function convert2Range100 (arr)
  {
  let factor = 1
    , max    = Math.max(...arr)

  if (max <= 10) factor = 0.1

  while (max > 100) 
    {
    factor *= 10
    max    /= 10 
    }
  return arr.map(v=>v/factor)
  }

console.log(JSON.stringify( convert2Range100( [7000, 500, 0, 850]) ))
console.log(JSON.stringify(  convert2Range100( [70, 550, 0, 1000]) ))
console.log(JSON.stringify(  convert2Range100( [7, 5, 0, 8.5]) ))
```

Comment: You reimplemented Math.log

Comment: @Frambot I do not have a good understanding about logarithms, my humble origins did not allow me to access the studies I would like to have. Looking at the downvote, I feel like someone is blaming me for this fact